# How to get customer_id from different table and avoid duplications with correct method in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Hi I am trying to get customer _id from  different tables Purchase order ,Sale Order and Consignments

Then I am looping through these Ids . Method I am using for this purpose is working perfectly but . I am afraid if there is a lot of data this method may get failed. Here is my method .

```
   $consignmentCustomerIds = Consignment::select('customer_id')->where('is_repeat', 0)->whereDate('created_at','>',date('2021-03-06'))->whereRaw('(is_group = "parent" or is_group is null)')->where('finalize', 0)->where('invoice_id', null)->distinct()->pluck('customer_id')->toArray();
        $poCustomerIds = PurchaseOrder::select('customer_id')->whereDate('created_at','>',date('2021-03-06'))->where('invoice_id', null)->distinct()->pluck('customer_id')->toArray();
        $soCustomerIds = SaleOrder::select('customer_id')->whereDate('created_at','>',date('2021-03-06'))->where('invoice_id', null)->distinct()->pluck('customer_id')->toArray();
        $spCustomerIds = StoragePeriod::select('customer_id')->whereDate('created_at','>',date('2021-03-06'))->where('invoice_id', null)->distinct()->pluck('customer_id')->toArray();

        $ids = array_merge($consignmentCustomerIds, $poCustomerIds, $soCustomerIds, $spCustomerIds);


        $customers = Customer::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();

        foreach ($customers as $customer) {

            CreateInvoiceOneByOne::dispatch($customer)->onQueue('invoice');
        }
```

Is there any better way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is to change `->get()` to `->cursor()` in the iteration:

```
//      $customers = Customer::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
        $customers = Customer::whereIn('id', $ids)->cursor();
```

The cursor method may be used to significantly reduce your application's memory consumption when iterating through tens of thousands of Eloquent model records.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOUR RELATIONS ARE SET PROPERLY**
I suggest to reduce database query. You can do this by chaning `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` within the customer request.

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
    $date = date('2021-03-06');

    $customers = Customer::whereHas('consignment', function($query) use($date) {
                                $query->where('is_repeat', 0)->whereDate('created_at','>',$date)->whereRaw('(is_group = "parent" or is_group is null)')->where('finalize', 0)->where('invoice_id', null);
                            })->orWhereHas('purchase_order', function($query) use($date) {
                                $query->whereDate('created_at','>',$date)->where('invoice_id', null);
                            })->orWhereHas('sale_order', function($query) use($date) {
                                $query->whereDate('created_at','>',$date)->where('invoice_id', null);
                            })->orWhereHas('storage_period', function($query) use($date) {
                                $query->whereDate('created_at','>',$date)->where('invoice_id', null);
                            })->get();

    foreach ($customers as $customer) {
        CreateInvoiceOneByOne::dispatch($customer)->onQueue('invoice');
    }
```

I set the `$date` variable before the query, so this way you can manipulate it at one place.

P.S. I am currently assuming the name of the relations.